# Date and time filter comparison doesn't work in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, eloquent, laravel-6

I want to create a table in a Laravel view showing all the meetings that are not concluded. But unfortunately, my table "meetings" (MySQL) has one column for the date (named "date"... type "date") and another column for the time (named "end_hour"... type "time").

Unfortunately, I am unable to find a way to do the correct query (I have problems with the "time side").
I've tried many times, but I see only the meeting with a date >= today. The hours don't seem to work correctly.

```php
public function index()
{
    $meetings = Meeting::all()
        ->where('is_active', '1')
        ->sortBy('start_hour')
        ->sortBy('date');

    // Here's the problem.
    $meetings = $meetings->filter(function ($meeting) {
        return $meeting->date > date('Y-m-d') || ($meeting->date === date('Y-m-d') && time() > strtotime($meeting->end_hour));
    });

    $this->getUsersTable($meetings);
    $this->getRoomsTable($meetings);

    return view('nextMeetings', compact('meetings'));
}
```

How can I visualize on the table only meetings that haven't concluded?

Comment: Laravel returns Carbon objects for dates and times, at least by default, so I'd have a look at the docs for Carbon.

Comment: Have you tried to do your converts using Carbon ?
https://carbon.nesbot.com/

Comment: OK I solved... there was the following problem: `time() > strtotime($meeting->end_hour)`. I changed it with `time() < strtotime($meeting->end_hour)`. However Carbon is very nice I will use it next times!